# Change DB in ADL LRS settings

Tags: python, django, mongodb, tin-can-api

I have set up the ADL LRS on a ubuntu server. By default it uses the Postgresql database. I have a simple question, How can I change the database? In place of Postgresql, I may want to use MySql, SQLite or MongoDB. As per this [article](http://www.adlnet.gov/adl_lrs/) we can do that is settings.py file present in your ADL LRS codebase. But what are the values to be put in here..? For my instance I want to use MongoDB.

I have searched a lot but found no help anywhere. Any suggestion is most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I know you want to change the backend to MongoDB, but first here is a wiki article on any changes you'd have to make to use a MySQL backend (https://github.com/adlnet/ADL_LRS/wiki/MYSQL-backend-support).

To change the backend in Django please see the Django docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/databases/).

If you want to use MongoDB there is a Django MongoDB-Engine you can try using (http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). After it is setup, I'm sure there will be conversion issues with the ORM models already created in the LRS that you will have to resolve.